Why the type of `e_lfanew` field in struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER(winnt.h) is LONG?
struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER from Win11 SDK:
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {      // DOS .EXE header
    WORD   e_magic;                     // Magic number
    WORD   e_cblp;                      // Bytes on last page of file
    WORD   e_cp;                        // Pages in file
    WORD   e_crlc;                      // Relocations
    WORD   e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
    WORD   e_minalloc;                  // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_maxalloc;                  // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_ss;                        // Initial (relative) SS value
    WORD   e_sp;                        // Initial SP value
    WORD   e_csum;                      // Checksum
    WORD   e_ip;                        // Initial IP value
    WORD   e_cs;                        // Initial (relative) CS value
    WORD   e_lfarlc;                    // File address of relocation table
    WORD   e_ovno;                      // Overlay number
    WORD   e_res[4];                    // Reserved words
    WORD   e_oemid;                     // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    WORD   e_oeminfo;                   // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    WORD   e_res2[10];                  // Reserved words
    LONG   e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header
  } IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;

Here e_lfanew is LONG type, but I found other version of winnt.h is:
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {
    WORD  e_magic;      /* 00: MZ Header signature */
    WORD  e_cblp;       /* 02: Bytes on last page of file */
    WORD  e_cp;         /* 04: Pages in file */
    WORD  e_crlc;       /* 06: Relocations */
    WORD  e_cparhdr;    /* 08: Size of header in paragraphs */
    WORD  e_minalloc;   /* 0a: Minimum extra paragraphs needed */
    WORD  e_maxalloc;   /* 0c: Maximum extra paragraphs needed */
    WORD  e_ss;         /* 0e: Initial (relative) SS value */
    WORD  e_sp;         /* 10: Initial SP value */
    WORD  e_csum;       /* 12: Checksum */
    WORD  e_ip;         /* 14: Initial IP value */
    WORD  e_cs;         /* 16: Initial (relative) CS value */
    WORD  e_lfarlc;     /* 18: File address of relocation table */
    WORD  e_ovno;       /* 1a: Overlay number */
    WORD  e_res[4];     /* 1c: Reserved words */
    WORD  e_oemid;      /* 24: OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo) */
    WORD  e_oeminfo;    /* 26: OEM information; e_oemid specific */
    WORD  e_res2[10];   /* 28: Reserved words */
    DWORD e_lfanew;     /* 3c: Offset to extended header */
} IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;

but here e_lfanew is DWORD, I'm not sure whether it's old version of winnt.h from Win9x, if so, what's the reason change to use LONG not keeping DWORD?
I searched a lot in google, but have no any informations. Some article tells e_lfanew is DWORD

e_lfanew: The last member of the DOS MZ Header is e_lfanew which is a DWORD that means it consist of last 4 bytes of the DOS MZ header. It holds the offset to the start of PE Header. This value is check by the PE loader of the windows system which offset to load for PE Header.

but it's LONG in winnt.h actually on his article:

The first 64 bytes of the PE file is known as DOS MZ Header which is define in winnt.h or windows.inc . The member of DOS MZ header structure is shown below.

typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {
   ...
   LONG   e_lfanew;
} IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;

Seems that some people thinks e_lfanew is DWORD, what is the reason that this situation occurred?

I would rather think that the official Microsoft SDK would be correct, and the code used for WINE might not be. With that said, DWORD makes more sense, but Microsoft are very keen on keeping their API's and structures very backward compatible.

The only ways this would make any difference if you tried to put the PE header at a negative offset (there is no valid way to do that) or at an offset > 2GB from the start (we can try to see if that works)

@user555045 IOW with long it would limit the size of a PE executable to 2GB which is more than large enough. (But OTOH, who once said that "640Kb should be enough for anyone" ;-) )

The SizeOfImage field is a DWORD in the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 and the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64. That places a hard limit of 4GiB on the PE image file size. However, some offsets in the file format are expressed as signed 32-bit values, bringing the maximum image file size down to 2GiB. With that, there is no practical difference between a LONG and a DWORD for the PE header offset.

If you check with the sizeof operator you can see that both types are 32 bits wide.

@OldBoy If, on the other hand, you checked std::is_signed for either type the expression would evaluate to true and false for LONG and DWORD, respectively. The byte pattern 0x80000000 means different things when interpreted as either type. That's pretty much at the core of this question.

It probably has something to do with mingw's roots, gcc started life in the Unix universe.  Long isn't the same there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models
